# Estimate for convex functions

Tags: real-analysis, functions, convex-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ be non-negative, convex and $f(0)=0$. Let $x,y\in \mathbb{R}, x<y$. Then
$f(x)\leq f(|x|)$. Further if $|x|\leq |y|$ then also $f(|x|)\leq f(|y|)$. So far I've tried to show this with the definition of convexity, but the estimates didn't really help me so far. Are there better ways to try ?

Comment: Your second statement does not seem to be true. Pick $f(z) = z^2$ and let $x = -5$, $y = 4$. Then $x < y$ but $f(|x|) = 25$, $f(|y|) = 16$.

Comment: You're right. I forgt something. Thanks !

Comment: There is still something wrong. $f(x) = \max(-x, 0)$ is convex, but $f(-1) = 1 > f(|-1|) = 0$. – What you can conclude is that $f$ is increasing on $[0, \infty)$ and decreasing on $(-\infty, 0]$.

Comment: Well, that's indeed even a counterexample for both cases. Thanks!